# Determine if the resulting value of a function is odd or even

Tags: algorithm, math

I am solving a hailstone problem, but with a twist, you are given the length, find the value of `x` if the hailstone starts with `1`

I thought it could be determined, if I alternatively change odd and even, and reverse the equation like so:

```
function r(len, prev, isEven) {
     if(len < 1) return prev;
     if(isEven) {
         return r(len - 1, prev * 2, !isEven);
     } else {
         return r(len - 1, (prev - 1) * 3, !isEven);
     }
}
```

Now I realized it wasn't just alternate seq., what mathematical concept should I apply in this problem.

Example:

if Len = 8, answer is 6

since:

6 -> 3 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1

Comment: http://xkcd.com/710/

Comment: In your example the length is 9 not 8.

Comment: The first start that gives a length of eight is 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1.

Comment: The inverse is not necessarily a single valued function. E.g 21, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 has a length of 8 as does 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1. The one with the lowest starting value is 20 though. So what do you want. All possible values of a length or the one with the lowest starting value?

Answer (score 2):

Just output `2^len` :)

Imagine, for `len = 8`, `6` is a valid answer, because `6 -> 3 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1`

again, `2^len` = `2^8` = `256` is also valid, because `256 -> 128 -> 64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1`

Comment: if it is 2^len? then it is always 256?

Comment: Nope, when `len = 7`, it will be `128` , when `len = 6` , it will be `64` , again when `len = 10` , it will be `1024` .... just like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function r(len , pre){
    if (len <1) return prev
    if ((pre-1)/3 == 1 && (pre-1)%3== 0) || ((pre-1)/3 > 1 && (pre-1)%3 != 0) || (pre<=3 && pre>=1) { 
    return r(len-1 , 2*pre)
    }
    elsif((pre-1)/3 > 1 && (pre-1)%3 == 0){
    return r(len-1 , (pre-1)/3) 
    }   
}
```